# What is wrong with this markup its not searching for the page

Tags: php

I have a code that is suppose to find if a page exists then use it as a extension. For example, when id=example, the included file would be 'example.php'. The include seems not to be working it does not look for the file.

```
<?php
$page = strip_tags($_GET['id']);
$page = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s]/", "", $page);
if($page=='' || $page=='index' || $page=='config')
{
?>
Hello!  Welcome to my site.<br />
<?php
if($logged_in==1)
{
    ?>
    If you would like to leave, please <a href='/logout.php'>Logout</a>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    If you are already a member, please <a href='/index.php?id=login'>Login</a>
    <?php
}
}
else
{
$filename = $page.".php";
if(file_exists($filename)) {
    include ''.$page.'.php';
}
}
?>
```

I am working on it just thought maybe somebody could offer some help. Why is my code not working?

Comment: Huge security hole right here

Comment: @JohnConde is right, but I will submit an answer.

Answer (score 1):

there is a huge security issue with this, but...

try this:

```
<?php
$page = strip_tags($_GET['id']);
$page = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s]/", "", $page);
if($page=='' || $page=='index' || $page=='config'){
?>
Hello!  Welcome to my site.<br />
<?php
if($logged_in==1){
?>
        If you would like to leave, please <a href="/logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php
} else {
?>
        If you are already a member, please <a href="/index.php?id=login">Login</a>
<?php
}
} else {
$filename = "$page.php";
if(file_exists($filename)) {
    include ("$page.php");
}
}
?>
```